# lock firefox developer edition in launcher

Tags: unity, firefox, google-chrome, launcher, icons

I've recently installed firefox developer edition on my machine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The installed firefox developer edition is located in `/home/firefox` folder. I have to start it manually by going there and double clicking on it. Is there any way whereby I can lock the binary file (`/home/firefox/firefox`) to the launcher (just like chrome and firefox icons).

Note: On click of the developer edition icon, it should open developer edition firefox, not the normal firefox. Currently both are shown in launcher as a single icon with multiple windows.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a .desktop file

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop
```

Then paste this inside, adapting the Icon and Exec path values:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Icon=/home/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
Exec=/home/firefox/firefox
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Search `firefox` using the dash: both the regular and developer versions should appear. Launch the developer version, right click on its icon on the Unity launcher and pin it.

Comment: Thanks for writing answer. I followed above steps, but I'm unable to see the developer edition while searching in dash. There is only one entry appearing for firefox (normal). Couldn't get any search results for 'developer'.

Comment: I'm on 16.04 and can't test on 14.04 right now. Open the ~/.local/share/applications folder, right-click on firefox-developer.desktop, properties, make it executable. Launch it with double-click. Once started you should see the Firefox dev icon on the Unity launcher.

Comment: Did it like you said, the executable took the correct icon I'd assigned, but there was an error message. It says "There was an error launching the application." What might be wrong? Also search in dash does not display developer edition of firefox, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After looking into other .desktop files in applications folder, I added "path=/home/firefox/firefox" with firefox-bin as starting program. Double clicking on it opened firefox developer edition and also searching in dash is showing entry for firefox developer edition. The only remaining thing that I want to do is lock it just like other programs in launcher. Now, right clicking on program icons in launcher not showing context menu (the menu to lock program in launcher). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: To pin an icon on the launcher you can also find it in the dash and then click and drag it on the launcher bar.

Comment: Did the above, also @Prime_Coder, which I upvoted too fast as it looked to be  in the right direction, but none of them work. I might have not understood what "with firefox-bin as starting program" means; I just entered the `Path=/home/firefox/firefox` (with uppercase as otherwise wont work) in the same .desktop file. But still no firefox in the dash (the Ubuntu apps menu that show by pressing the OS button + A...

Answer (score 0):

So, a `.desktop` file is basically the Linux equivalent of a Windows shortcut file. These files are also what is used to populate the Unity launcher. As a beginner, the impression I got reading this and related questions is that `.desktop` files are specifically for representing icons in the launcher, but this is not the case.

So first, create a `.desktop` file for the Firefox Dev edition, as explained in the other answer. Many answers on this site will then tell you to put that file in `~/.local/share/applications`, implying that that folder is where Unity keeps the items for the launcher. This did not appear to be the case at all on my computer. In fact on my computer, there doesn't seem to be any correlation at all between the items in that folder and the items on the launcher.

Instead, right click on the file, and in "Properties", turn on the "Run as executable" permission. Then double click the file. Firefox should launch, and the icon in the launcher should be the blue icon. If not, make sure the paths for Exec and Icon in the `.desktop` are correct. Now simply right click the icon in the launcher and lock it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `firefox-aurora` as the StartupWMClass in the Desktop Entry. It worked for me.

## Step by Step

1. Open the terminal and type the following command to edit the launcher file:

```bash
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/firefox-developer.desktop
```

2. Paste the following content in the file

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web in the Developer Edition
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox --class firefox-developer %u
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
StartupNotify=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox -private-window
```

Save it and it will be ready

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).